# How to create a list of objects?

Tags: python, list, instance

How do I go about creating a list of objects (class instances) in Python?

Or is this a result of bad design? I need this cause I have different objects and I need to handle them at a later stage, so I would just keep on adding them to a list and call them later.

Comment: Do you mean a list of type objects (`[type(x), ... ]`) or instances of a class (`[1, 2, 3]`)?

Comment: @Skurmedel: class instances. I mentioned it specifically in the question :)

Comment: @Alfred: hehe, I just find class instances a bit ambiguous, but I see what you mean now through the selected answer :P

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Storing a list of object instances is very simple

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

my_objects = []

for i in range(100):
    my_objects.append(MyClass(i))

# Print the number attribute of each instance

for obj in my_objects:
    print(obj.number)
```

Comment: Where you pass "object" in the first line, is that an actual object or just a number signifying that object instance's number?

If I were to write
 my_objects(1), 
I would call to the first object, but I don't think the 1 being passed in is an object. This might be entirely orthogonal to the educational purposes of the original response, but it would help me on a different, related topic I'm struggling with. Thanks.

Comment: T'was hoping there was a shiny special syntax for this :(

Comment: @Brad English, that indicates that `MyClass` inherits the properties of an `object`

Comment: The `i` in `MyClass (i)` refers to the `number` in the class's `__init__` function.

Answer (score 25):

You can create a list of objects in one line using a list comprehension.

```
class MyClass(object): pass

objs = [MyClass() for i in range(10)]

print(objs)
```

Comment: This is really clean syntax.

Comment: Slight detail:  objs = [MyClass(i) for i in range(10)]

Comment: @Brainless, in this answer, the MyClass() initializer does not take an argument (in one of the other answers, it does...).

Comment: The usual python idiom is to use `_` for loop variables that aren't referenced in the loop body (i.e. `objs = [MyClass() for _ in range(10)]`)

Answer (score 5):

The Python Tutorial discusses [how to use lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Storing a list of classes is no different than storing any other objects.

```
def MyClass(object):
    pass

my_types = [str, int, float, MyClass]
```

Answer (score 4):

In Python, the name of the class refers to the class instance.  Consider:

```
class A: pass
class B: pass
class C: pass

lst = [A, B, C]

# instantiate second class
b_instance = lst[1]()
print b_instance
```

Answer (score 2):

I have some hacky answers that are likely to be terrible... but I have very little experience at this point.

a way:

```
class myClass():
    myInstances = []
    def __init__(self, myStr01, myStr02):
        self.myStr01 = myStr01
        self.myStr02 = myStr02
        self.__class__.myInstances.append(self)

myObj01 = myClass("Foo", "Bar")
myObj02 = myClass("FooBar",  "Baz")

for thisObj in myClass.myInstances:
    print(thisObj.myStr01)
    print(thisObj.myStr02)
```

A hack way to get this done:

```
import sys
class myClass():
    def __init__(self, myStr01, myStr02):
        self.myStr01 = myStr01
        self.myStr02 = myStr02

myObj01 = myClass("Foo", "Bar")
myObj02 = myClass("FooBar",  "Baz")

myInstances = []
myLocals = str(locals()).split("'")
thisStep = 0
for thisLocalsLine in myLocals:
    thisStep += 1
    if "myClass object at" in thisLocalsLine:
        print(thisLocalsLine)
        print(myLocals[(thisStep - 2)])
        #myInstances.append(myLocals[(thisStep - 2)])
        print(myInstances)
        myInstances.append(getattr(sys.modules[__name__], myLocals[(thisStep - 2)]))

for thisObj in myInstances:
    print(thisObj.myStr01)
    print(thisObj.myStr02)
```

Another more 'clever' hack:

```
import sys
class myClass():
    def __init__(self, myStr01, myStr02):
        self.myStr01 = myStr01
        self.myStr02 = myStr02

myInstances = []
myClasses = {
    "myObj01": ["Foo", "Bar"],
    "myObj02": ["FooBar",  "Baz"]
    }

for thisClass in myClasses.keys():
    exec("%s = myClass('%s', '%s')" % (thisClass, myClasses[thisClass][0], myClasses[thisClass][1]))
    myInstances.append(getattr(sys.modules[__name__], thisClass))

for thisObj in myInstances:
    print(thisObj.myStr01)
    print(thisObj.myStr02)
```

Answer (score 0):

if my_list is the list that you want to store your objects in it and my_object is your object wanted to be stored, use this structure:

```
my_list.append(my_object)
```

Answer (score 0):

We have class for students and we want make list of students that each item of list is kind of student

```
class student :
    def __init__(self,name,major):
        self.name=name
        self.major=major


students = []
count=int(input("enter number of students :"))
#Quantify
for i in range (0,count):
    n=input("please enter name :")
    m=input("please enter major :")
    students.append(student(n,m))
#access
for i in students:
    print (i.name,i.major)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

I think what you're of doing here is using a structure containing your class instances. I don't know the syntax for naming structures in python, but in perl I could create a structure obj.id[x] where x is an incremented integer. Then, I could just refer back to the specific class instance I needed by referencing the struct numerically. Is this anything in the direction of what you're trying to do?