# access class attributes from another without inheritance? use an array of classes as input

Tags: python, numpy

I have a class:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def method_A(self):
        return self.a
```

Now, I have another class B:

```
class B():

    def __init__(self, c,d):
        self.c = c
        self.d = d

    def method_B(self):
        # do computations with a and b from class A
        # return A.a * c
```

One solution is to have B inherit from A but that means that it inherits all attributes of A which is something that I don't want.

For example it will be :

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self,a,b,c,d)
        A().__init__(self,a,b)
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
```

So, I have to initialize my B class with `def __init__(self,a,b,c,d)` all arguments (from A and for B) , right?

Is there a way I can avoid that ?And still have access to class A attributes and methods?

---------- **UPDATE 1** --------------------------------------

Updated according to the answers.

I want to be able to use an array of class A as input to class B.

I tried:

```
import numpy as np

class B():

    def __init__(self, c, d, the_a):
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
        self.the_a = the_a


    def method_B(self):
         for i in self.the_a:
            return self.the_a[0][0].a * self.c

a = np.array([[A(2, 4), A(3,5)]])
b = B(4, 4, a)
print(b.method_B())
```

and I am receiving : the value `8` .

But obvious I am not correctly using the loop in method_B.

I am using only the 0 index, but I can't figure!

------- **UPDATE 2** ------------------------------

I am almost there..

```
 def method_B(self):
     for idx, x in np.ndenumerate(self.the_a):

        self.the_a[idx].a = self.the_a[idx].a * self.c
        self.the_a[idx].b = self.the_a[idx].b * self.c

    return self.the_a
```

Now, it returns me `[[<__main__.A object at 0x7f165426c9b0>
  <__main__.A object at 0x7f165426c898>]]` .

Is there a way I can receive the updated array like:

```
np.array([[ A(8, 16), A(12,20)]])
```

Comment: If you want to initialise an instance of `A` in `B` you're going to have to pass the arguments one way or another

Comment: You've given b a numpy array of `A` instances, do you want `B` to have multiple `A`? If not then just give `B` a single `A` instance instead of a list of them. Otherwise your `B.__init__` needs to handle multiple `A` instances.

Comment: @StevenSummers:yes, I want B to have as input an array of A instances.

Comment: `self.the_aV1 = the_a.a` and `self.the_aV2 = the_a.b` isn't going to work as `the_a` is a numpy array which as the error message states doesn't have an attribute `a`. What do you want `the_aV1` and `the_aV2` to be since you want multiple `A`?

Comment: @StevenSummers:the a and b are the values of the A class.So, i want to extract these values from the input array.So, regarding a values , I have : 2 and 3.regarding b values , i have : 4 and 5.And I want to make calculations based on these values ( as in the method_B)

Comment: I'd recommend using a list instead of an array, `a = [A(2, 4), A(3,5)]`.  It'll be easier to iterate over that.  And with content like `class A`, you can't do any array math of the array form of `a`.

Comment: @hpaulj:But numpy arrays are more effective in terms of memory consumption and speed.Because , I may use thousand of lines of this array.

Comment: In update 1 you were returning from the loop too early; instead you should collect values from all the loops and return that.  In the second update you appear to correctly update values in `a`.  But the method itself returns `None` - because there isn't a `return` statement.  I think you should focus on making `method_B` work right as a standalone function.  Once that works you can turn it into a method.

Comment: Arrays like yours, with `dtype=object` are not more efficient.  They just contain pointers to your `A` objects, just as lists do.  The fact that you have to iterate on `a` to perform this simple multiplication proves that the array form doesn't help.  The only thing it adds is the multidimensional shape.

Comment: @hpaulj, I agree.  Your function doesn't return anything, hence it's return value is none.  If your functions returned what you wanted to use, then the statement could work. So the_a would have to return something you want.

Comment: @NickHale:I have updated my post (update 2).I want to return the whole array and not the object.

Comment: It's tricky to replicate, but my first thought is 'return list(self.the_a)'  Then you can convert that list to an array if you need to.  Perhaps try the multiplication operation in a list comprehension.  That may stop it giving you an array of objects.

Answer (score 2):

You need an instance of A:

```
def method_B(self, the_a):
    return the_a.a * self.c
```

Comment: But how can i initialize the A instance?Don't I have to use the init parameters of A in the B class?Can you give me a more complete example please?

Answer (score 2):

Hold an instance of class A in class B.

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def method_A(self):
        return self.a

class B():

    def __init__(self, c, d, the_a):
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
        self.the_a = the_a

    def method_B(self):
        return self.the_a.a * self.c

a = A(1, 2)
b = B(3, 4, a)
```

Comment: And if I have many instances that I want to supply to B ?If I have an array(numpy) or list of A instances?

Comment: Instead of only one instance of A, you can pass a list with instances of A. In your method_B you can iterate over it and do whatever you nedd to do.

Comment: Can you please give me an example?because , I am using something like : `a = np.array([[A(2, 4), A(3,5)]])` and a loop in method_B but I have an error about accessing the attribute from class B init.

Answer (score 2):

To follow on the previous answer, if you create an instance of A:

```
a = A(a, b)
```

then, in class B, you can pass in that instance as a single argument and access any method(or variable for that matter) by referring to it's instance:

```
class B():
    def __init__(self, c, d, instance_of_a):
    self.c = c
    self.f = d
    self.e = instance_of_a.[the method or variable you want from class A]
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: And if I have many instances that I want to supply to B ?If I have an array(numpy) or list of A instances?

Comment: Ok, a list would of objects would be the way I would go here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182183/creating-a-list-of-objects-in-python)  I don't think numpy can handle a list of objects.